# Parse.com using master key

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to update user's record in the users class from another logged in users but the problem I'm facing now is that I'm getting an error that it's not allowable except by using the master key. I've tried to add Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey() in my code by eclipse doesn't recognize it and i can't find any clues surfing internet for a week now...Please help !!!

Here is the logcat exception :

```
com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot save a ParseUser that is not authenticated.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be logged in as the user you're trying to modify. A possible solution would be to  call a Cloud Code function and use the Master Key to do this.

The Cloud Code guide is here: https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide

Comment: Thanks Arcayne...I will have a look into this guide.. :)